# Android Listview load image from String click

Tags: android, string, image, listview, load

I have a list of items, after click on list new activity is open with details.
Problem is that I can not implement - image load after click on specific string from detailed activity.
For example, in MainActivity, there is:

```
String one[] = {"dog", "cat", "horse", "snail"};
String two[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};
String three[] = {"111", "**222**", "333", "**222**"};
```

Open app, click on second list item (cat) and open new activity with details (all strings for cat)
I need, in this case, after click on "String three" - if string is 222, open image (drawable/222.jpg), in this case that is for "cat" and "snail".
And after click on "333" show image 333.jpg ...

If it is possible, it would be best to open image with back button, to go back to detailed activity.

**Simplified MainActivity:**

```
String one[] = {"dog", "cat", "horse", "snail"};
String two[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};
String three[] = {"111", "222", "333", "222"};



List<ItemsModel> itemsModelList = new ArrayList<>();

ListView listView;

CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);


    for(int i = 0;i < one.length;i++){

        ItemsModel itemsModel = new ItemsModel(one[i],two[i],three[i]);

        itemsModelList.add(itemsModel);

    }

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(itemsModelList,this);

    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if(id == R.id.searchView){

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl;
    private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelListFiltered;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl, Context context) {
        this.itemsModelsl = itemsModelsl;
        this.itemsModelListFiltered = itemsModelsl;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsModelListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsModelListFiltered.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_items,null);


        TextView one = view.findViewById(R.id.one);
        TextView two = view.findViewById(R.id.two);

        one.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getone());
        two.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).gettwo());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("main activity","item clicked");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemsActivity.class).putExtra("items",itemsModelListFiltered.get(position)));

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

---

//// ItemModel:

```
public class ItemsModel implements Serializable {

    private String one;
    private String two;
    private String three;

    public ItemsModel(String one, String two, String three) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
        this.three = three;

    }

    public String getone() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setone(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public String gettwo() {return two; }

    public void settwo(String two) { this.two = two; }

    public String getthree() {return three; }

    public void setthree(String three) { this.three = three; }

///
```

If you need `Itemactivity` or activity.xml I will copy.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I did not manage to implement this in code -> if string is 222, open image (drawable/222.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file inside a `res/drawable` folder, the file name cannot be started with a number, like `111.jpg`, `222.jpg`, etc. So to do this you can add a prefix that starts with a letter like `image_111.jpg`, `image_222.jpg` and so on.

**Solution**

In `ItemsActivity`, use [getIdentifier(String, String, String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get a resource id (`R.drawable.image_222`) by resource name (`image_222`).

```
public class ItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;

    ItemsModel itemsModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            itemsModel = (ItemsModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("items");
            textView2.setText(itemsModel.getone());
            textView.setText(itemsModel.gettwo());
            textView3.setText(itemsModel.getthree());
            textView3.setClickable(true);
            textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Get drawable name
                    String drawableName = "image_" + itemsModel.getthree();

                    // Find drawable resource id by drawable name
                    int drawableResId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                            drawableName,
                            "drawable",
                            getPackageName());

                    showImageDetail(drawableResId);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showImageDetail(int imageResId) {
        // Using a dialog or activity to open image detail.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
        builder.setView(imageView);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

**Update**

> First issue is recognition of "222" when String three[] is for example "xxx & 222", so I need recognition of "222" inside hole string. Some bigger string will have both 222 and 333 inside, can I click on both? One will show image_222 other image_333.

This is quite complicated a little bit. For example, the `three` value might be

> 333 yyy 444 xxx & 222

In this case, you must loop through the string and find the image number, like 333, 444, 222, and calculate its start and end index, then use [SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method to set click listener on each image number.

In the following code, I will use

- [Java Regex](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary) to find all image numbers in the `three` value.
- [SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method to set click listener on image numbers.

Code

```
public class ItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;

    ItemsModel itemsModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            itemsModel = (ItemsModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("items");
            textView.setText(itemsModel.getone());
            textView2.setText(itemsModel.gettwo());

            String three = itemsModel.getthree();
            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(three);

            String regex = three;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3})");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(regex);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String imageNumber = matcher.group(0);
                int numberStartIndex = three.indexOf(imageNumber);
                int numberEndIndex = numberStartIndex + imageNumber.length();

                builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                        showImageDetailByImageNumber(imageNumber);
                    }
                }, numberStartIndex, numberEndIndex, SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                regex = three.substring(numberEndIndex);
                matcher = pattern.matcher(regex);
            }

            textView3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            textView3.setText(builder);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the image drawable (image_222.jpg) based on its number name (222)
     * @param imageNumber The image number like 111, 222, 333.
     */
    private void showImageDetailByImageNumber(String imageNumber) {
        // Get drawable name
        String drawableName = "image_" + imageNumber;

        // Find drawable resource id by drawable name
        int drawableResId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                drawableName,
                "drawable",
                getPackageName());

        // Using a dialog or activity to open image detail.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(drawableResId);
        builder.setView(imageView);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

> Second issue is that inside drawable folder image name must have small letters and numbers. I will need with capital letter string (for example A222)

In Android, the file name inside drawable must start with a lowercase letter, so I think you only use a prefix for image inside that folder, such as `image_`, `img_` or any prefix that fits your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Son, maybe I did not explain good. I am not wish to open image_222 in second activity, there will be like this in second activity:   1 row: cat, under that- 2 row: bbb and under that "222", and in second activity, after clicking on "222" it should open image_222. In new activity or pop-out "window.

Comment: @Namma I updated the answer, please let me know if it fits your requirement.

Comment: I just added new answer, to make it clear, and there is attached image how it should look like. Thanks for help

Comment: @Namma Please see my updated answer based on your code.

Comment: There is some problem, I can't enter to second activity when click on the list, on cat or whatever. It opened download folder. I will check code again

Comment: Something is wrong, with this I can not enter in second activity. Please consider that String three[] must be some text no image. After click on text in second activity - image should be loaded. Without click on text 222 no image should be displayed. So string three will stay 222 no image_222. Thanks

Comment: This is visual answer https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdyyC.jpg

Comment: You means the three text will only number like 222, but when click on it, will load image file with name image_222.jpg, is that correct?

Comment: What is the image file name for text "222" in drawable folder?

Comment: That is correct. After click on list Cat it is opened second activity with "details for Cat, for example Cat, bbb, 222 and if click on 222 image should be opened. Image name can be image_222.jpg, I think I put it good in photo -(visual answer) above. Thanks for helping Son

Comment: I updated the answer, please check again.

Comment: Same thing, when I click on List there is no second activity at all, download folder is opened insted, so I can't check code for image. I just copy code to ItemsActivity, my code was ok for second activity, there is some collision probably.

Comment: Could you please double check the code where you start the second activity, it seems there is something goes wrong in your code.

Comment: Wait, everything is ok. Let me check, I will write for 5 min.

Comment: Take it easy, please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Make sure there is a file named `image_222.jpg` in drawable folder.

Comment: I have problem to try it on device, but on emulator work perfect. YOU are the BEST Son. Thanks for time and patience.

Comment: Try to uninstall then install the app again on the device.

Comment: Can we adjust code a little. I have 2 issues, it is not so important, but if it is possible will be good. First issue is recognition of "222" when String three[] is for example "xxx & 222", so I need recognition of "222" inside hole string. Some bigger string will have both 222 and 333 inside, can I click on both? One will show image_222 other image_333. Second issue is that inside drawable folder image name must have small letters and numbers.I will need with capital letter string (for example A222. Most important part is already solved by Son, if this is complicated, just ignore it.

Comment: @Namma I update the answer, please check again.

Comment: That is it. Big thanks again. (and sorry for submitting here in comments, I can't start chat discussion with this points)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just made a it visual, it should be like this.

In this moment, first and second activity runs ok, but that is it. Now I need to implement in code part for second activity, like in the image I give.
When click on "222" (in second activity) it should open drawable/image_222.jpg
When click on "333" (in second activity) it should open drawable/image_333.jpg
String 222 will be on few places, for example I give for Cat and for snail.
So if I understand it should be something like this: If "three is" "222" on click show "drawable image_222.jpg" (I know this looks bad, I just simplified it)

Down is short ItemActivity:

```
  TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;

ItemsModel itemsModel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_items_preview);


    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getExtras() != null){
        itemsModel = (ItemsModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("items");
        textView2.setText(itemsModel.getone());
        textView.setText(itemsModel.gettwo());
        textView3.setText(itemsModel.getthree());


    }
```

///
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdyyC.jpg